# Mock a TSV source with Scalding JobTest

Tags: scala, mocking, csv, scalding

I'm having a hard time making a unit test for my scalding Job.

My Job expects a file with three fields:

```
  TextLine(args("input"))
    .map('url -> ('fetchedUrl,'date,'info)){
  ...
```

Naively I would've expected that the *fields* got mapped as a nTuple, without needing any further setup. But from my test I get that it's not like that and some further contract needs to be stablished:

```
JobTest[com.kohls.crawler.Miner]
  .arg("input", "inputFile")
  .arg("output", "outputFile")
  .source(TextLine("inputFile"), List(("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test" ,"Mon Apr 14 15:08:11 CDT 2014", "extra info")))
  .sink[(String,Date,Array[Byte])](Tsv("outputFile")){ ... }
```

This currently fails with `cascading.tuple.FieldsResolverException: could not select fields: [{1}:'url'], from: [{2}:'offset', 'line']`. So I *guess* that I need to declare the TSV fields in some kind of way before feeding it as TextLine's input.

Most documentation I've found is spotty in this regard.
What is the correct why to define this test?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `Tsv` instead of `TextLine`. `Tsv` takes the declared fields as second input parameter. Your job would look like this:

```
Tsv(args("input"), ('fetchedUrl,'date,'info), skipHeader = false/true).read
  .map(...)
  .write(Tsv(args("output"), writeHeader = false/true)
```

And your job test like this:

```
JobTest[com.kohls.crawler.Miner]
  .arg("input", "inputFile")
  .arg("output", "outputFile")
  .source(Tsv("inputFile"), List(("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test" ,"Mon Apr 14 15:08:11 CDT 2014", "extra info")))
  .sink[(String,Date,Array[Byte])](Tsv("outputFile")) { ... }
  .run
  .finish
```

Comment: Ok. got it there. But the consumer part (the code that gets exercised by the test throws key error): `by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: Tsv(inputFile,'fetchedUrl', 'date', 'info',false,false)`

Comment: mmm, shouldn't be... Isn't that argument just a way to map data to some symbol? why should it matter what name is it?

Comment: Ah, ok... Yes, those are tracback formatting issues. The code is using only symbols...

Comment: The error must be inside your job then. I'd suggest to make a very simple job first to make sure it's not the test case that's causing the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Of course you can mock a TextLine in your test. The trick is to supply the hidden `'line` field.

```
    JobTest[com.kohls.crawler.Miner]
      .arg("input", "inputFile")
      .arg("output", "outputFile")
      .source(TextLine("inputFile"), List((
        0 -> "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test" , 
        1 -> "Mon Apr 14 15:08:11 CDT 2014", 
        2 -> "extra info")))
      .sink[(String,Date,Array[Byte])](Tsv("outputFile")){ ... }
```